# How to use android app login user id to set cookies for webview on loading website into webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

How to use android app login user id to set cookies for webview, when the website is loaded into webview? So please help, I want my website to use user login cookies by using android login id.

Comment: So you want to generate a cookie by your app based on Google Account and then use it with webview inside your app? Have you tried anything? And please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. StackOverflow is not based on "please give me code" but "i tried this code <your code> and <your problem>, please help".

Comment: grammar fixed

tag android-studio removed